# Monitoring script performance on a shared host

Tags: php, resources, monitoring, shared-hosting

I'm planning to run a PHP script periodically via cron on a shared hosting provider. Based on my localhost development, the script does not utilize too much of CPU. However, I would like to monitor the script runs/usage so as not to exert excess strain on the server and hence potentially result in an account limit.

What is the best way to monitor the memory and CPU usage of the script (with the additional feature of having the performance reports being e-mailed)? Since I'm on a shared host, I will not be able to install apps.

Thanks

Answer (score 0):

You can write your script in the below way. Their is a default function in php to check the memory usage but in few servers running windows, if they are disabled, their is a work around as well. Analyze the below code and try to get the idea. Hope it helps.

```
function getMemUsage()
{

        if (function_exists('memory_get_usage'))
        {
            return memory_get_usage();
        }
        else if ( strpos( strtolower($_SERVER["OS"]), 'windows') !== false)
        {
            // Windows workaround
            $output = array();

            exec('tasklist /FI "PID eq ' . getmypid() . '" /FO LIST', $output);            
            return substr($output[5], strpos($output[5], ':') + 1);
        }
        else
        {
            return '<b style="color: red;">no value</b>';
        }
}

$message = getMemUsage();
$subject = "Memory USage";

mail("xxx@xxx.com",$message,$subject);
```

Comment: memory_get_usage does exist but it returns the memory currently allocated to PHP ( http://in2.php.net/manual/en/function.memory-get-usage.php ). On a shared host, that does not give an accurate value of the memory consumed by my script individually

Comment: First use phpinfo().Then you get to see all the specs of the host, most of which apply. Some hosts might have some resource limits on individual user accounts to make sure that one user doesn't use the resources of the whole server. To figure that out, you'd have to contact the host.

Comment: Already done that. My host does not enforce hard constraints. In any case, my original question for monitoring the script performance still stands. Not sure I understand the reference to phpinfo()

Comment: From phpinfo(), you can get the memory limits. Based on that you can compare your usage.

Comment: Memory limits never work well with shared server. You will always get drastic difference even if its not your application fault. The script i wrote will intimate you the memory usage. From php info you know the limits. That will give you an idea.

Comment: I am already using a similar function/code but it is not useful. Does not work in my case. Thanks for your help though